# Run a embedded linux`s code, memery begins at 22M, decreases to about 6M slowly, and quickly up to about 22M，and then decreases to about 6M

Tags: c, linux

1. Running environment: haisi3516ev200, cross compile: arm-himix100-linux-gcc, kernel: linux-4.9.37
2. When I run an embedded Linux code, memory begins at 22M, decreases to about 6M slowly, and quickly up to about 22M,and then decreases to about 6M slowly... I thought it would be because of a memory leak, but I can't figure it out. I user free to check memery, like this (uint:k):

22284
21900
21772
21324
19500
19176
18792
18056
16904
16296
15560
14888
14216
12680
11448
10008
8536
6992
6756
22352
20656
20336
19472
18672
17968
15440
11040
69609
22088

3. The code is simple.

```
void main()
{
    int sockfd;
    char ip_addr[IP_ALEN] = {0};
    struct sockaddr_in s_addr_in;

    char buffer[1024];
    int ret = -1;
    int len =0;
    int conn_state, i;

    int32_t mach = 0,macl = 0;

    printf("\n thread send device info start \n");
    while(1)
    {
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        if(sockfd == -1)
        {
            printf("socket error! thread exit \n");
            break;
        }


        memset(&s_addr_in,0,sizeof(s_addr_in));
        s_addr_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ini_info->server_ip); 
        s_addr_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
        s_addr_in.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

        //set tcp keepalive
        set_tcp_keep_alive(sockfd);

                //connet
        conn_state  = 0;
        for(i = 0; i< 200; i++)
        {
            usleep(10000);
            ret = connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)(&s_addr_in),sizeof(s_addr_in));
            if(ret == 0)
            {
                conn_state = 1; 

                ret = local_inet(ini_info->net_type,ip_addr,&mach,&macl);
                if (0 != ret){
                    printf("get local ip failed");
                    return NULL;
                }
                printf("ip_addr = %s, mac = %06x%06x \n", ip_addr, mach,macl);

                break;
            }
        }

        if(conn_state == 0)
        {
            printf("connect failed \n");
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }


        printf("connect success \n");

        int cnt = 0;
        while(1)
        {
            sleep(5);

            memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "{\"type\":0,\"opcode\":1,\"information\": {\"id\":\"112233445566\"},\"status\":{\"power\":100,\"temp\":56}}");
            cnt = strlen(buffer);
            printf("buffer = %s,    strlen(buffer) = %d\n", buffer, cnt);
            ret = write(sockfd,buffer,cnt);
            if(ret <= 0)
            {
                printf("send status info error \n");
                break;
            }
            printf("report device info to ai-box success \n");

        }
        close(sockfd);
    }
    return ;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, it cannot be compiled. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Would that be a memory leak, it wouldn’t reset to 22M. So what grows is probably some cache. Maybe even that of stdout.

If that’s system cache, it’s OK as Linux frees that memory on demand quickly (so other programs like `top` don’t even include it in used).